# Making table row with iframe filling whole remaining screen

Tags: html, css, iframe, height, width

This is what I need to do: 
http://s27.postimg.org/ancbbaa6r/111.png
That is what I've done:
http://s27.postimg.org/87ahxfs43/222.png

Don't mind about fonts, I will change them Later.

I can't change HTML and use JS. Only CSS.
Any help?

CSS:

```
table {
width: 100%;
background-color: #f3c035;
padding: 10px;
font-family: "Arial", Arial, serif;
color: white;
}

iframe {
width: 100%;
}

.lewa {
background-color: #f3dfab;
width: 25%;
padding: 15px;
vertical-align: top;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: black;
}

.prawa {
background-color: #f3ecd9;
padding:15px;
vertical-align: top;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: black;
width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/szablon.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <th colspan="2">
            <p class="naglowek">
                Sugerowane w programie nauczania algorytmy do omówienia w ramach przedmiotu.
            </p>
            <hr/>
        </th>
        <tr>
        <td class="lewa">
            <p class="brown"> Menu: </p>
            <ul class="brown">
                <li><a target="tresc"
                    href="
                    http://www.algorytm.org/algorytmy-matematyczne/algorytm euklidesa.html
                    ">Największy wspólny dzielnik</a></li>
                <li><a target="tresc"
                    href="
                    http://www.ordona.internetdsl.pl/pascom/download/informatyka/algorytmy.pdf">Najmniejsza wspólna wielokrotność</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="prawa">
                <iframe nama="tresc" style="width": 100%; height: 95%"> </iframe>
                <p class="brown" style="text-align: right;">  Copyright 2013</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code mate:

```
 table {
width: 100%;
background-color: #f3c035;
padding: 10px;
font-family: "Arial", Arial, serif;
color: white;
height: 100%;
}

iframe {
width: 100%;
}

.lewa {
background-color: #f3dfab;
width: 25%;
padding: 15px;
vertical-align: top;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: black;
}

.prawa {
background-color: #f3ecd9;
padding:15px;
vertical-align: top;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: black;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

}
```

I just added

> height: 100%

in table {}

Remember that you have to fix the line:

```
 <iframe nama="tresc" style="width": 100%; height: 95%"> </iframe>
```

to:

```
 <iframe nama="tresc" style="width: 100%; height: 95%"> </iframe>
```

Look, you've added one extra " after width.

You have to add your th inside of a tr:

```
<tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <p class="naglowek">
                    Sugerowane w programie nauczania algorytmy do omówienia w ramach przedmiotu.
                </p>
                <hr/>
            </th>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I get this after adding height: 100% http://postimg.org/image/ptlaqzo0v/full/
The question is how to make th just as big as text.

Comment: To make the text big, you should add .naglowek { font-size: 20pt; } in your css.

Comment: No, I want to make table header smaller, not text bigger. Table header has to be as big as it needs to fit this text in.

Comment: Sorry I got it. Try: .naglowek {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}
th {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

Comment: Remember to add your th inside of a tr. (<tr><th</th></tr>)

Comment: Ok. Fixed it. I just added th {
height: 1px;
}
I don't know how it works tho xD

Comment: Thanks for help anyway.